# Can uneven ACQ treatment be corrected on decorative objects?

Tags: wood, pressure-treated

I bought some "pineapple" post caps made of treated pine. When they arrived, I was taken aback to see, rather than an overall greenish tinge, splotches and patches of green. As my plan has been to leave these unstained, I will probably have to send them back-- unless someone knows how to "fix" this problem? Additionally, what caused these caps to look like they have green splotchy paint on them?

[image: image description]

Comment: Please use the edit button to update your question, don't post your changes to this question as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Fresh [Alkaline Copper Quaternary(ACQ)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_copper_quaternary) treatment leaves the wood very wet.  In a month of dry conditions (in the sun), they will dry out and be much less splotchy.  The green will eventually be gone, going to gray in 12-18 months.

I know you didn't want to stain, but consider a light 'cedar' tone to even things out, until the green fades.

Once dry (3-5 weeks), you can stain for a more even color (water or oil based, )

Part of the unevenness comes from a mix of end grain (very absorptive), face grain and knots (non absorptive).  Pre-treatment of the end grain (usually at the top of turnings) with a sanding sealer (25% finish, 75% solvent) will help the stain finish evenly.